# Rating Title Differences with ICAO CPL

Tags: pilot-certification, multi-engine, instrument-rating

I graduated from an integrated ATPL programme in Turkey. Rating part of my CPL is comprised of two lines. Goes like:

IR/ME Valid until ...

MEP(land) Valid until..

However, my friend from my class(with the same exact training) got this CPL issued with only one line in the ratings part. Goes like:

MEP(land) IR Valid until ...

I think they will function the same but anybody have an idea on the style difference with these two CPL's and what could be the reason why?

Comment: Are the two dates the same in your case?

Comment: Nope they are different dates, but i also saw another friends licence with two lines with the same exact date.